# Websockets - force protocol

Tags: html, websocket, handshake

I am having problems getting Chromium/Firefox to handshake with my node.js install since they both use the hybi10 protocol now (which node WebSocket apparently doesn't support yet).

Am I right in thinking that doing...

```
new WebSocket( 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000','draft-ietf-hybi-00' );
```

... should force the browser to use an older protocol? It doesn't seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The second argument is a sub-protocol and not related to the version of the WebSocket protocol being used by the browser. Each browser implements a single version of the WebSocket protocol. Servers often implement support for multiple protocol versions.

Perhaps the [Node 'ws'](https://github.com/einaros/ws) module might work for you. There is also [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) which is higher level communication library that uses WebSockets if it can but includes fallbacks if the WebSocket transport is not available.

Comment: Yeah, it's the node ws module that I'm using. I'll have a look at Socket.IO

Comment: einaros/ws should be working. What sort of error are you getting from the server and/or browser (open Chrome's Javascript console).